# Parameter based expressions in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, expression

I would evaluate two conditions in "when" syntax of my Jenkinsfile.
In particular, I need to check when params.x is true and params.y is true.
Can I insert both in the same expression with the "and" operator?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From jenkins [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when):

> ```
> expression
> Execute the stage when the specified Groovy expression evaluates to true, for example: when { expression { return params.DEBUG_BUILD } } 
> Note that when returning strings from your expressions they must be converted to booleans or return null to evaluate to false. 
> Simply returning "0" or "false" will still evaluate to "true".
> ```

So if you insert a valid groovy statement it should work.

Alternatively you can use `allOf` statement, e.g.

```groovy
when {
  allOf {
    expression { params.x == true }
    expression { params.y == true }
  }
}
```

Comment: When is the `return` keyword required?  Half the examples I see have it and the other half don't.

Comment: what examples are you referring to?

Comment: Apparently it's optional.  A groovy block returns the last value evaluated whether you put a `return` keyword or not.